# Http2CallStream.call.on error when reading data from firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I created a collection called "config" 
using the "firebase->Database->Cloud Firestore" Service.

And I want to read the all data inside it
And this is the error I get:

> ```
> Error:
>     at Http2CallStream.call.on (C:\Users\alihe\Desktop\test\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call.js:68:41)
>     at Http2CallStream.emit (events.js:187:15)
>     at process.nextTick (C:\Users\alihe\Desktop\test\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call-stream.js:71:22)
>     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
>   code: 13,
>   details: '',
>   metadata: Metadata { options: undefined, internalRepr: Map {} } }
> ```

```
Code:

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require('./serviceAccountKey.json');

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: serviceAccount.databaseURL
});

const db = admin.firestore();

db.collection('config').get()
.then(snapshot => {
    console.debug(snapshot);
})
.catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: Are all of your node modules fully up to date?

Comment: I just installed this two packages Do I need another package ?!

"@firebase/database": "^0.5.3",
"firebase-admin": "^8.5.0"

Comment: You should uninstall @firebase/database.  firebase-admin will bring in everything it needs to work on its own.

Comment: I deleted the node_modules and I only have the firebase-admin in the  package.json
After installing the packages I still have the same error

Comment: If you have predictable steps to reproduce this from scratch, please file a bug with firebase-admin on GitHub.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node

Comment: I'm experiences the same...